# How to finish activity/screen in react native using route-flux module in react native like android?

Tags: react-native, routes, react-router

Here are all routes. i want to finish splash screen when i go to home screen. Is that possible?

```
const Routes = () => (
   <Router>
      <Scene key = "root">    
         <Scene key = "splash" component = {SplashScreen} hideNavBar= {true} initial = {true}  />
         <Scene key = "login" component = {LoginScreen} hideNavBar= {true}  />
         <Scene key = "home" component = {HomeScreen} title = "Home" />
         <Scene key = "signup" component = {SignupScreen} hideNavBar= {true} />
         <Scene key = "phoneverification" component = {PhoneCodeVerification}  hideNavBar= {true}/>
         <Scene key = "signupwithemail" component = {SignupwithEmail}  hideNavBar= {true} />
         <Scene key = "emailverification" component = {EmailVerification}  hideNavBar= {true} />
         <Scene key = "success" component = {SuccesScreen}  hideNavBar= {true} />
         <Scene key = "setupprofile" component = {SetupProfile}  hideNavBar= {true}/>
         <Scene key = "forgotpassword" component = {ForgotPasswordScreen} hideNavBar= {true} />
         <Scene key = "resetcodephone" component = {ResetCodePhoneScreen} hideNavBar= {true} />
         <Scene key = "resetcodeemail" component = {ResetCodeEmailScreen} hideNavBar= {true} />
         <Scene key = "resetpassword" component = {ResetPasswordScreen} hideNavBar= {true} />
      </Scene>
   </Router>
)
export default Routes
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Actions.replace() we can replace scene it is useful to replace screen to home screen or login screen alternative solution is (recomended) Actions.({type:'reset'})